# Will SockeIOClientDotNet work for Windows Phone 8.1 RT, and Socket IO 1.2.x based web server?

Tags: c#, websocket, socket.io, chat, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to develop a chat application in windows phone 8.1 (am not using the silverlight version), I created a server with Node.JS and with socket.io. But am not able to connect to the server from my windows phone App. I tried using both SocketIO4Net and SockeIOClientDotNet. Both where not connecting. Is there any alternative options? Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try use [WinJs 3.0](http://try.buildwinjs.com/#listview) connect with [socket.io](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/46553AE5/D71EBB87) it really work.